# random selection from a deminishing list

Tags: list, random, selection

Consider you have a deck of 52 cards. Randomly select one (top one for this example). Now you only have 51 cards. Next select from these remaining cards (next one on top). and so on until there is only one card remaining. How would I write an excel formula to simulate this diminishing list selection?

Comment: If the selections are all random, all cards have an equal likelihood of being the last one picked.  Just pick one of the 52 cards at random to simulate this most efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list containing two columns

1. column containing numbers 1-52
2. column2 containing RAND() function

Sort the list on column 2.